# Sending session id to server from Flash or Java Applet when cookies are marked as httpOnly

Tags: java, flash, jsessionid, httponly

Is it possible to use either Flash or a Java Applet to upload files to a server, where the target URL is protected via some form of authentication and the cookies are marked as 'httpOnly', without having to either disable httpOnly or include the session id in the target URL or as another parameter in the POST?

That is, using something like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), is there any way to send the session id to the server without having to add it to the target URL (e.g. http://www.example.com:8080/mysite/upload;jsessionid=ABCDEF)<strike>, as a parameter in the POST that Uploadify performs</strike>, or disabling the httpOnly flag?

For reference, we are using Java 1.6 and Glassfish 3.1.

I've looked around, but it seems that it's not possible - I have to pick one of the three options above.

Given that, which of those options is the 'least evil'? Alternatively, if there's some guidance out there as to how to deal with this situation, a pointer to it would be most appreciated.

I can't just not use Flash/Java, as we use it for file uploads, and we need to allow the user to select multiple files at once - expecting them to add files one-by-one to standard HTML upload selects won't fly. We need to support older versions of IE, so going to HTML5 also won't fly.

Asking the users to upload an archive *might* fly, but it would require them to change their behaviour, and would mean that a lot of validation that we currently do client-side wouldn't be available, and that's a pain when you're dealing with large files and a slow link. So, again, not at all ideal.

Comment: The `jsessionid` is passed around as either an appendage to the path as you have shown above or via a cookie. I'm not aware that it is ever a POST parameter.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had thought you could put a little bit of hackery together and manually get the session id out of the post parameters, and set it that way. But that doesn't appear to work, as the HttpRequest interface doesn't provide a setter method for the session id.